# Get unsaved node from route parameter

Tags: 8, entities, nodes, routes

**What I want:** In `hook_media_presave` I want to set a field value according to the same field on the referring node.

By the `referring node`, I mean the node where the media entity is created through an entity reference field.

I don't know if this is possible at all, but if it is, then how?

My current approach is to get the node from the route like this inside the presave hook:

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
```

**My problem:** The node I get from the `routeMatch` doesn't contain the new changes. Is there a way to somehow get them using the `routeMatch`, or is there another way to get the node.

I thought maybe the media entity had some kind of `getReferringEntity()` method, but no.

Is this the correct approach, or am I wrong?

Comment: How is the referring node linked to the media entity? What is the user journey?

Comment: The media entity is a reference field on the node.

Comment: Sounds like a form issue. At that point, the changes may not be there on the node. Maybe if you do your logic in a custom submit callback and get what you need from form_state?

Comment: The reason you won't find that method is that it wouldn't really make sense for it to be there - a media entity being saved has no reliance on the action having been taken through an entity reference field on an entity form. Is there a reason you decided to go bottom to top rather than top to bottom, though? In `hook_node_presave` you'll have access to both the pieces of information you need, that's where I'd do it

Comment: @Clive, my thoughts was. I need to update all media entities even though they are refenced in a paragraph e.g. and there might be different field names for the different entity reference fields. So I thought if I somehow could get the node in a media presave I didn't have to know every single field and its location.

Comment: You still don't - that stuff is queryable. `$node->getFieldDefinitions()` will get you a list of fields attach to the node, you can loop through that and check for any with a type of `entity_reference_revisions` (or whatever it is), with a target type of paragraph, and get the paragraph entity from it. Then loop through `$paragraph->getFieldDefinitions()` and look for a media reference fields. If you find one that you're interested in, set its value to the desired value from the node and you're done

Comment: Thanks, @Clive. You saved my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help from @Clive I found a solution:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_update().
 */
function MY_MODULE_node_update(\Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {
  foreach ($node->getFieldDefinitions() as $definition) {
    if (!in_array($definition->getType(), ['entity_reference', 'entity_reference_revisions'])) {
      continue;
    }
    if (!$definition->getSetting('target_type')) {
      continue;
    }
    if ($definition->getSetting('target_type') == 'media') {
      $media = $node->{$definition->getName()}->entity;
      if ($media) {
        $media->groups->target_id = $node->groups->target_id;
        $media->save();
      }
    }
    if ($definition->getSetting('target_type') == 'paragraph') {
      $paragraph = $node->{$definition->getName()}->entity;
      if ($paragraph) {
        MY_MODULE_update_media_items($paragraph, $node->groups);
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Set groups on all media items referenced in a paragraph.
 *
 * @param $paragraph
 *   The paragraph.
 * @param $groups
 *   The groups to set.
 */
function MY_MODULE_update_media_items($paragraph, $groups) {
  foreach ($paragraph->getFieldDefinitions() as $definition) {
    if (!in_array($definition->getType(), ['entity_reference', 'entity_reference_revisions'])) {
      continue;
    }
    if (!$definition->getSetting('target_type')) {
      continue;
    }
    if ($definition->getSetting('target_type') == 'media') {
      $media = $paragraph->{$definition->getName()}->entity;
      if ($media) {
        $media->groups->target_id = $groups->target_id;
        $media->save();
      }
    }
    if ($definition->getSetting('target_type') == 'paragraph') {
      $paragraph = $paragraph->{$definition->getName()}->entity;
      if ($paragraph) {
        MY_MODULE_update_media_items($paragraph, $groups);
      }
    }
  }
}
```